# Neovim LSP Phpactor not finding classes

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-php, astronvim

I have a project like this:

```
- fruity/
      - composer.json
      - vendor/
   - appley/
      - various.php
   - orangy/
      - composer.json
      - vendor/
      - src/
```

It's basically two projects in one tree.

I'm using [astronvim](https://astronvim.github.io/) with nvim-lspconfig and phpactor as the LSP. PhpActor is working ok normally, but in this project it refuses to parse the orangy/ sources; it won't find classes defined in there.

I've set the `root_dir` correctly; viewing `:LspInfo` shows it correctly set to `/path/to/fruity/`

I've set the command to include `-vvv` but can't see anything useful in the logs; I'm not sure the vvv worked.

Here's the config snippet I'm using in lsp.server-settings:

```lua
      phpactor = {
        cmd = { 'phpactor', 'language-server', '-vvv' },
        root_dir = function(startPath)
          print("root_dir running"); -- just to confirm this works; it does.
          local rp = (require 'lspconfig.util').root_pattern
          for _, pattern in pairs({".thisIsDocRoot", "index.php", ".git", "node_modules", "index.php", "composer.json"})
          do
            local found = rp({pattern})(startPath)
            print(pattern, found) -- this works
            if (found and found ~= '') then return found end
          end
          return nil
        end,
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd still like to know how to debug this stuff better, but my problem was solved by clearing my `~/.cache/phpactor/`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with phpactor at all, but it looks like this is *probably* a problem in phpactor rather than neovim or the LSP integration you're using. If you can reproduce it again, it may be worth keeping a backup of that cache directory and reporting a bug at phpactor.